# How can fix problems with Eclipse? Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I had Ubuntu 17.04 until yesterday beacuse I have done the update at Ubuntu 17.10. 
Before the update, Eclipse (with java) perfectly worked, now I have some problems. After the update I can't create a new Java Project, I choose to unistall eclipse and then reinstall it but it dosn't fix my bug. Now I have problems with exevutable launcher of eclipse. Eclipse dosen't work. Help me please.

Comment: What are the error seen please we need these!

Answer (score 0):

I recently had this issues and luckily I had a working install on 17.10 before installing the DBeaver plugin. It worked fine until I rebooted an attempted to load eclipse. I found that if you have DBeaver tab open it will not open in 17.10. The fix I came up with if you know you have DBeaver installed..

1. Change the name of your workspace to you can get a prompt to make a new one.
2. After you create a temp workspace
3. Go to Help>About Eclipse>Installation Detail
4. Uninstall DBeaver
5. Change workspace name back to original name
6. File>Switch Workspace > Other
7. Restart Eclipse Manually if it doesn't start on its own